# Python 3.x Interaction with other Program GUIs

Tags: python, user-interface, pywinauto

I'm looking for a Python 3.x library that is able to allow interaction with other programs.
For example, I already have some sort of command-line interface which I have developed in python, and I
want to be able to enter, say "1", and have another program open.  From here, I wish to hit another
input like "2" and have it manipulate the GUI that opens (for example, for it to "click" the Configurations
dropdown bar and select an option, perhaps modify a few settings, apply, and then possibly also automatically
enter some text).  The reason I'm doing this is for test automation.
I've already tried using pywinauto, but I've found it to not be compatible for Python 3!  :(
Is there another possible approach to this?  Thanks in advance!!!
P.S. I may have forgotten to mention that I'm using Windows 7 but with Python32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/). It lets you automate clicks and other actions based on region or matched graphic. Fairly smart. Is there a reason you're dead set on using py3?

Comment: Sadly, yes, I already made this humongous script all in py3 and all the other libraries I'm using are for py3 specifically... :(

Comment: I've tested with Sikuli and it is working perfectly with Python 3!  Just what I was looking for...Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Py3-compatible pywinauto released! New home page: http://pywinauto.github.io/

P.S. I'm maintainer of pywinauto.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but have a look at [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which enables you to move the mouse and press keys. I used it for the following snippet which launches an emulator and presses keys.

```py
import pyautogui as pg
import os
import time

game_filepath = "../games/BalloonFight.zip"
os.system(f"fceux {game_filepath} &")

time.sleep(1)

keys_to_press = ['s', 's', 'enter']

for key_to_press in keys_to_press:
    pg.keyDown(key_to_press)
    pg.keyUp(key_to_press)

time.sleep(2)

im = pg.screenshot("./test.png", region=(0,0, 300, 400))
print(im)
```

A more detailed expalanation can be found here: [Reinforcement learning to play Nintendo NES games](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/reinforcement-learning/nintendo/reinforcement-learning-nintendo-nes-tutorial/)

Answer (score -2):

I created a pywinauto fork on GitHub that's compatible with Python 3: 
https://github.com/Usonaki/sendkeys-py-si-python3

I only did basic testing, so there might still be some circular import related problems that I haven't found.